# Select the last element that is not empty (innerText !== "") of a class with querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I'm try to select the last element that is not empty of a class.

For example, here I would like to select the second element:

```
<span class="test">A</span>
<span class="test">B</span>
<span class="test"></span>
<span class="test"></span>
```

But because the innerText changes (with the actions of the user), I can't just use

```
document.querySelector(".test:nth-of-type(2)");
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work :

```
document.querySelector('.test:not(:empty):nth-last-of-type(1)');
```

```js
function myFunction(){
  document.querySelector('.test:not(:empty):nth-last-of-type(1)').innerText = "test";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="test">A</span><br>
<span class="test">B</span><br>
<span class="test"></span><br>
<span class="test"></span><br>

<input type="button" value="change 2nd element" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.test').filter(item => !item.innerText).at(-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use querySelector for this? I would suggest this:

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('.test') // all with test class
  .filter(elem => elem.innerText !== '') // only not empty
  .at(-1) // last element

// or, if you need backward browser compatibility:
document
  .querySelectorAll('.test') // all with test class
  .filter(elem => elem.innerText !== '') // only not empty
  .reverse()[0]
```

Comment: I understand the logic but can't figure out to make it work : https://jsfiddle.net/3dpo6bc1/ :(

Comment: Maybe, your browser doesn't support Array.prototype.at(). It's a new function. Try using .reverse()[0]

Comment: There are other methods too, @Myk, such as simply calling `pop()`, in place of `at()` since the array's already been filtered to contain only non-empty elements.

Comment: I'm still struggling :(

Comment: Does the jsfiddle work on your browser ?

Comment: @MykAdo, try to do like this: ```Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test'))```